# Having trouble with a script to move Hyper-V VM's

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I am trying to write a script that will take the hyper-V host as an input as well as the search string for the list of VM's I want to move...this is all via SCCM VMM, and its all 2012R2

Here is what I have so far...

```
$VMHOST = read-host "Enter the HyperV host you want to move your VM's to"

$SEARCHPATTERN = read-host "Enter the search pattern for the VM's you want to move"

$VMLIST = Get-SCVirtualMachine | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*$SEARCHPATTERN*"} |format-table name -HideTableHeaders

foreach ($VMM in $VMLIST)
{

Move-SCVirtualMachine -VM $VMM -VMHost $VMHOST

}
```

If I run it, I get...

> Move-SCVirtualMachine : Cannot bind parameter 'VM'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData" value 
>   of type "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData" to type "Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.VM".
>   At C:\Users\jfalcon\Desktop\vmmove.ps1:6 char:27
>   + Move-SCVirtualMachine -VM $VMM -VMHost $VMHOST
>   +                           ~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-SCVirtualMachine], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.SystemCenter.VirtualMachineManager.Cmdlets.DeployVMCmdlet

Any ideas? Is the $VMLIST output not formatted correctly?

Comment: i am not familiar with these cmdlets but Have you tried it without the `format-table`

Comment: Then it returns the table names in front of each VM name, not sure if that would fly with the loop. I used the format-table to remove the table headers and just return a list of VM names.

Comment: Format table destorys the objects. We need to remove that and I know we dont need it... looking at it more. can we see the output of just this `Get-SCVirtualMachine | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*$SEARCHPATTERN*"}`

Comment: It basically prints everything, its too much to paste here. If I sub $SEARCHPATTERN with part of the name of the VM, it will just print all the VM details, and its lots of stuff. Format table just got me the names of the VM. Not the host, memory, path, HBA, etc...that just running the command as is. Its too long for me to even post here with the character limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never** use `format-anything` if you intend to continue processing the data. People use it for "nice" output to text file ( if you like console tables ) but it is for appearances only. PowerShell has converted your object into `[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData]` for the purpose of displaying on screen. At that point the original object is destroyed.

You need to extract the right property from your `Get-SCVirtualMachine` using `Select-Object -Expandproperty` of just using dot notation if you PowerShell Version at least 3.0.

```
$VMLIST = Get-SCVirtualMachine | 
    Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*$SEARCHPATTERN*"} | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Ah, I see. I will check that out and plug it into the rest of the script and let you know.

Comment: Works! One other question, I added a | out-null to the end of the line: Move-SCVirtualMachine -VM $VMM -VMHost $VMHOST, and that supresses the output. BUT, how can I get it to display the job with get-scjob? I want it to display status while the job is running in the script.

Comment: @Actif2009 Glad to hear it. I am not familiar with the cmdlet output so I am not sure how to help you with that. Either way that sounds like a new question.

Comment: Looks like I have to use the write-progress cmdlet to do what I want. I will open a new question if I run into trouble. Thanks!